# Bookshelf.js - How to get 'hidden' fields for one query only?

Tags: javascript, arrays, node.js, knex.js, bookshelf.js

I have the following Bookshelf model :

```
Bookshelf.model.extend({
  tableName: 'users',
  hidden: ['password']
}, { 
  async getBy(filter) {
    return await this.query({where: filter}).fetch();
  }
})
```

As you see, the field `password` is hidden (because I usually don't want it to be shown).
But, I need it to connect my user (when doing the hash comparison) :

```
const user = await userModel.getBy({email: req.body.email});
if (await bcrypt.compare(req.body.password, user.password)) { 
  // here user.password is undefined because it is hidden
}
```

Is there a way to shortcut the visibility plugin and get the password without having to do things like directly using `knex` (`Bookshelf.knex.raw()`) ?

Best regards,

Answer (score 7, accepted):

OK, since I've found a solution, I'll answer my own question and I hope it will help some people :

14 days ago (30/06/2017), the issue [#1379](https://github.com/bookshelf/bookshelf/pull/1379) has been merged.

It provides the following functionnality :

> Adds ability to override options specified during forging with the options specified to toJSON directly.

[Here](https://github.com/bookshelf/bookshelf/commit/8540e22007c0f0f566291c4d859d8a83f0d374c2) is the commit, the tests show how it works.

For my case, I do the following :

`const user = (await userModel.getBy({email: req.body.email})).toJSON({hidden: []});`

`hidden` is an empty array, so it overrides the previous hidden property (`hidden: ['password']`) and get the passwords to be shown.